# Remove "Save your information" from Microsoft Edge when automating

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

My automation will fill out a form and then I get the "Save your information" pop-up which I cannot click on (using automation). I need to click something that's right under the box so I'm currently stuck. I've tried a couple of variations with EdgeOptions but none seem to do the job. What I've tried so far:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--bwsi");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("suppress-message-center-popups");
```

[Microsoft Edge 'Save Your Information' pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnPDS.png)

I know you can go to Settings > Personal info > Disable "Save and fill custom info" but this doesn't work in my case because my edge comes from a shared drive so its not my personal settings.
Disabling "Show Autofill predictions" under edge://flags/ also doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough environment to test your problem. Can you create a new profile? Just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROxR2.png). If this can be done, you could disable `save and fill custom info` and  use this profile in EdgeOptions. Something like this: `edgeOptions.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data");`

Comment: Congratulations, you have solved this issue. I'd like to put the solution as an answer and hope that you can accept the answer. I think it can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you can create a profile in Edge as shown below, you could disable option `save and fill custom info` and use this profile in **EdgeOptions**.

[image: v]

Code like this:

```
edgeOptions.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data");
```